# How to use snoopy class in php

Tags: php, snoopy

I've been trying to find out how to use snoopy class in php. I'm trying to search anything from google using snoopy. i found out that the form of google search is name=q and the action=/search

how to set my snoopy code to a correct code.

```
$s=new Snoopy();
$form=array("q"=>"spiderman");
$s->httpmethod = "GET";
$s->submit("http://www.google.com",$form);
echo $s->results;
```

i got a 405 result.

Comment: That's a pretty bad looking library. Take a look at Guzzle instead ~ http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: @Phil i think it only support post method?

Comment: Err, the very first example on the [home page](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#guzzle) shows a GET request

Comment: @Phil. oopppss. sorry my bad. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// include snoopy library
require('Snoopy.class.php');
// initialize snoopy object
$snoopy = new Snoopy;
$url = "http://t.qq.com";
// read webpage content
$snoopy->fetch($url);
// save it to $lines_string
$lines_string = $snoopy->results;
//output, you can also save it locally on the server
echo $lines_string;
?>
```